# FileMaker Web Viewer javascript step fails when used as a local file: window.open()

Tags: javascript, filemaker, window.open

I ran into an odd issue with a bit of Javascript that is running in a Web Viewer (WV) in a FileMaker database.  (For those that don't know, FileMaker is an integrated UI/DB platform which has a 'web viewer' object, which is a cut down version of a web browser that runs inside the solution.  It is NOT a full web browser.)

We have had this WV+Javascript working for quite a while now, in files that are hosted using FileMaker Server (FMS).  There's a button on a layout that opens a pop-out window that contains this web viewer.  This web viewer is a media player, with pause/play buttons; it has some special functions for capturing the current video position and reporting it back to the database: it has some buttons and reads keystrokes, and calls back to the open FMP file to affect changes there.  Again, this has been working fine when the file is hosted on FMS.

But then we wanted to make a trial/demo version of this file, and have the user run it locally or offline.  In testing this offline file it was noticed that the pop-out window web viewer stopped calling back to the open file.  (FileMaker Pro also registers a new URL scheme, "fmp://".  This can be used to make callbacks to the database from web viewers that are inside that database.  So the code was changed to use the '$' reference in the "fmp://" URL, which causes the FileMaker client software to reference the currently open file of the given name.)  But even with that fixed, there was one step that was failing still.

To effect these 'callback' events from the WV+javascript to the FM file, the javascript was using this code:

```
window.open('fmp://' + fmdbHost + '/' + fmdbFilename + '?script=keyPressed&param=' + e.keyCode, 'form_b');
```

(Here, the variable 'fmdbhost' = "$", as noted; 'fmdbFilename' =(nameoftheopenfile); 'e.keyCode'=(keypressed); "form_b" is an iframe that is defined in the HTML of the page.)  This code (when it's working on the hosted environment) does not actually open a new window; that's OK, I don't want it to open a new window.  It just a technique used to execute the URL and trigger functionality in the FileMaker world.

My solution/workaround, was to instead use this code:

```
window.location.href = ( 'fmp://' + fmdbHost + '/' + fmdbFilename + '?script=keyPressed&param=' + e.keyCode );
```

This appears to work out just fine, but I'm curious to know why the original step was failing when it's run locally.  This was working if the file was hosted...so why would that fail if the file is being run locally?  Does it do some kind of URL verification, and not like the "fmp://" or perhaps the "$" part?  If so...why isn't it doing this when using 'window.location'?  (If I used the original 'fmdbHost' definition - which used an IP Address - it would at least execute the window.open() method and attempt to open the "fmp://" URL.  It's just that when run locally this ended up being the wrong file - it needs to use the "$" reference to affect the currently open file.)

The specification for 'window.open()' indicates that the second parameter is a window name (sounds more like a reference to the new window).  So in the original code the 'form_b' reference is attempting to reuse the iframe defined in the HTML as the conduit for the call.  But is that iframe even an actual window 'reference' initially?  Does something parse the DOM and extract iframes and add them to the list of current 'windows'?

I'm using FM 15.01 for testing/development, on OS X 10.11.6.  Ultimately, this will have to run on Windows as well...but that can be ignored for now.

Thanks,
J

Comment: You did not specify a version of FileMaker or your OS. My other comment - this is a problem solving site more than a discussion one. You should really take it to one of the FileMaker forums. Most of the examples of using fmp protocol in JavaScript which I saw on the web use window.location, btw. WebViewer is designed for a single window, no surprise your script is unstable.

Comment: 1) Updated to reflect FM version and OS.  2) You could look at it as a problem:  window.open() broke when run locally.  3) Have tried the forums - getting crickets; figured this would be a much more javascript oriented audience here.